# Exception even though code is surrounded with try/catch block

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, exception

I have a code for fetching json. It works perfectly fine, when my device is connected to internet, but it crashes if there is no internet connection.
I have surrounded that particular line of code with try / catch block, but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Of course, I can do a workaround, and first check if there is internet connection and then call the method I need, but I want to understand this.

Why @catch isn't triggered in this case, and what to do to handle this exception in this case?

Here is the code:

```
@try {
NSError *error;

NSMutableDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                             JSONObjectWithData:_jsonData
                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                             error:&error];
...
@catch (NSException *exception) {

        [_indicator stopAnimating];
        _indicator.hidden = YES;
        [self popUp];

}
```

So, the exception occurs when trying to populate json dictionary.

Comment: what exception? you can't catch exc_bad_access

Comment: Your question implies the exception is due to the lack of internet connection, but you don't show any networking code. Can you please post *all* of the relevant code? Also, what exception are you getting?

Comment: Well I have noticed that an exception occurs when I turn the internet off, So that's how I figured out that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data `_jsonData` seems to be obtained before `try~catch` block, and then the source of the issue should be out of the block. Then you need to find out where the data is obtained from the internet, and install the `try~catch` block at there.